# NDB query by keys value

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, flask, google-cloud-datastore

New to using Python NDB.

I have something like:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    seen_list = nbd.KeyProperty(kind=Survey, repeated=True)

class Survey(ndb.Model):
    same = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

I want to be able to query for users that have not seen certain surveys.

What I am doing now is:

```
users = User.query(seen_list != 'survey name').fetch()
```

This does not work. What would be the proper way to do this? Should I first query the Survey list to get the key of the survey with a certain name? Is the != part correct?

I could not find any examples similar to this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, if your survey is a repeated property, it won't work that way.  When you query a repeated property the datastore tries EVERY entry in your list, and if one works, it'll return the item.  So when you say "!= survey name 1", if you have at least ONE entry in your list that isn't "survey name 1", it'll come back as positive, even if another result IS "survey name 1".

it's uninstinctive if you come from an SQL background I know.... the only way to go around that is to go programatically and evaluate the ones your query returns.  It comes from the fact that, for repeated values, Big Table "flatten" your results, which means it creates one entry for EVERY value in your repeated attribute.  so as it scans, it eventually finds one "correct" line with your info, grabs the object key from there, and returns the object.